# I Can't run SparkBWA

Tags: apache-spark, alignment, genome

I'm a beginner in learning bid data tools in genomics and I don't know what's the problem
the command and the error details at this link (It's so long so I couldn't copy it here)

https://egyptscholars-my.sharepoint.com/personal/asmaa_ali_egyptscholars_org/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=ltfC3N59y0NBMotKvzZQF1LKoIvIoRwaUg3SbkOAuBo%3d&docid=0aa67f1b2872e4335bc09876e1c94f46c

Comment: This question is useless and should be deleted.  Provide a complete self-contained question, summarized with exact errors, exact problem, and what you expect. Unfortunately this is coming up in google search results.  http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

The error message states you are missing you fastq files in `/user/root/ERR000589_2.filt.fastq` and `/user/root/ERR000589_2.filt.fastq`.

Are they really there?